# Make file "%.o: %.c" gives "No rule to make target"

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am learning about makefiles using the following guide: [makefiletutorial](https://makefiletutorial.com/)

So far, everything was going fine until this example of using "%":

```
objects = foo.o bar.o all.o
all: $(objects)

# These files compile via implicit rules
# Syntax - targets ...: target-pattern: prereq-patterns ...
# In the case of the first target, foo.o, the target-pattern matches foo.o and sets the "stem" to be "foo".
# It then replaces the '%' in prereq-patterns with that stem
$(objects): %.o: %.c

all.c:
    echo "int main() { return 0; }" > all.c

%.c:
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f *.c *.o all
```

The example works fine. However, I when I replace the `$(objects): %.o: %.c` part with `%.o: %.c` and run `make all` or `make -r all` commands I get `make: *** No rule to make target 'all.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

Shouldn't the "%.o" target in the `%.o: %.c` rule allow the making of any ".o" files? Why do I have to use static pattern matching for the files of the list and not directly use a rule for all ".o" files?

Here is the full non-working makefile:

```
objects = foo.o bar.o all.o
all: $(objects)

# These files compile via implicit rules
# Syntax - targets ...: target-pattern: prereq-patterns ...
# In the case of the first target, foo.o, the target-pattern matches foo.o and sets the "stem" to be "foo".
# It then replaces the '%' in prereq-patterns with that stem
#$(objects): %.o: %.c
%.o: %.c

all.c:
    echo "int main() { return 0; }" > all.c

%.c:
    touch $@


clean:
    rm -f *.c *.o all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a rule:

```
%.o: %.c
```

This is a *canceling* of a rule.  See [Canceling Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).  It's not possible in GNU make to create prerequisites with no recipe using pattern rules.

Comment: Though a noop recipe such as `true` will mostly have the same effect as no recipe

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on whether you want any `.o` files to be created or not.  If you add a recipe like `true` (or just the empty string) then that defines a rule to build a `.o` file, to be "don't do anything".  This is very unlikely to be what the user wants.  There's really no need for this rule anyway, because make has a built-in rule that already says that `%.o` files depend on `%.c` files, and it provides a recipe for building them.  Even if this syntax worked (which it doesn't) it would be redundant in this situation.

Comment: But shouldn't it work with the -r flag since it disables implicit rules? If there are no implicit rules for a "%.anything: %.anything", would it also be considered as canceling a rule?

Comment: In this particular case (a pattern rule to generate .o files) a noop action does not make any sense.  But for some other pattern rule, there might be a reason to do it.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the pattern rule exists or not: a pattern rule with no recipe will cancel it if it exists and is just a no-op if it doesn't.  It would be gross and impossible to use reliably for patterns with no recipe to cancel a pattern rule if it exists, or define a prerequisite relationship if no pattern rule exists.